# Nodejs javascript added to button not responding

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a button inside a table for each database entry. As forms cannot be in tables I can't use the form to make a request. I added a little portion of javascript to each button that should make a get request with the database id and redirect to a different page. It does not seem to be working. I tested creating a dummy form and making the same get request on the page and that worked. Any ideas why this isn't working?

Nodejs file Router

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/testRedirect/:id', (req, res) => res.render('pages/about'))

module.exports = router
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <% include ../partials/header.ejs %>
</head>

<body>
    <% include ../partials/nav.ejs %>

        <div class="container">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Id</th>
                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Edit</th>
                        <th scope="col">Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <% results.forEach(function(r) { %>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">
                                <%= r.id %>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="row">
                                <%= r.name %>
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <button type="submit" id=<%=r.quiz_id %> class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $(function() {
                                        var id = <%=r.id %>
                                        var idString = "#" + id
                                        $(idString).click(function() {
                                            $.get('/testRedirect/' + id)
                                        })
                                    });
                                </script>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="submit" id=<%=r.Id %> class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                </script>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <% }); %>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <form action="/testRedirect/1" method="GET">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form> 
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you realy need a script block for every button. Can't you use onclick attribute:

```
<button type="button" id=<%=r.quiz_id %> onclick="location.href='/testRedirect/#<%=r.quiz_id %>'" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
```

Comment: I didn't even think about on clickevents! Haven't used javascript in a while. Its weird that it fixed my problem. Do you by chance know why that worked?

Comment: Can you tell what happend after sending it via $.get()? Any errors?

Comment: No errors, looking at the network pannel it shows a 200 and to the correct url. It just doesn't redirect after. Is it because there is no location.href?

Comment: The $.get() method is just an ajax request. So, you receive the data (the hole page in your case) as a response, but do nothing with it. You need a callback to handle the response $.get("...", function(response){ /* your code here */});

Comment: Ahhh right so my javascript function was making the call but doing nothing. Figured adding res.render() would redirect. I tried res.redirect too. I should read up a little more on those